# Half h-bridge circuit with LED and multiple buttons

Tags: transistors, led, diodes, h-bridge

The logic is basically that when I click the SW1, it should light up D5 and run Q2 and Q4. If I then clicked SW2, D5 would run but should run Q3 and Q1. Additionally, D6 should lit up when neither is clicked.

The circuit:

[image]

Comment: please draw the schematic to convention ... +V at top, GND at bottom, input on left, output at right

Comment: Are you sure your circuit is correct?  It seems that your NPN transistors are wired incorrectly.

Comment: Please use the component reference designators (S1, D2, etc) rather than "first button, second LED...", so we know which component you are referring to.

Comment: The schematic now shows SW2 and SW4 connected in parallel, and connected to all three transistor bases.

Comment: R4 and R6 should connect from the right side of the switches to ground to turn off the transistors when the switch is not pressed.  As it is now, the transistors will always be on.  What do you mean by "... run current normally" and "The reverse is done in SW4."?  Try to draw the schematic in "landscape mode", with the switches on the left and motor on the right, and the components spread out a bit so we can easily see how things are connected without having to laboriously tracing wires.

Comment: @PeterBennett I did that on a breadboard though I couldn't find any switch that has 4 legs in kicad. Also, the forward and reverse mode refers to how the current should flow. When SW2 is clicked, the current flows forward as I said and turning the motor clockwise. The reverse is done in SW4

Comment: You can't reverse the motor with a single half-bridge - you need to switch both sides of the motor to reverse it.  Your schematic is nonsense - no connection to Q1 emitter or Q2 collector.  You still have R4 and R6 connected across the buttons - the left end of both resistors should go to ground.  You should abandon this circuit and look for other examples of using a bridge for motor control.

Comment: @PeterBennett did your suggestions,

Comment: The thing is, clicking SW1 doesnt work but SW2 runs the motor in reverse direction.